# iPhone: UISegmentedController on custom UIToolBar shifted down

Tags: iphone, ios

I have UISegmentedControl on toolbar, when I add custom background drawing method for toolbar segmented control moved nearly 2px down, so it is not vertically centered. Here is corresponding image link, see toolbar on the bottom of the [screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/users/Naira_as/folders/Default/media/45b6eca9-08fe-46d2-94d3-e8212f90a081) and code how I've added segmented control to toolbar:

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentedItems];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(tabChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
button1.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
button2.width = kSegmentedControlFrame.size.width;
button2.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
UIBarButtonItem *button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
button3.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;

CGFloat y = self.contentView != nil ? self.contentView.frame.origin.y + self.contentView.frame.size.height : kToolbarFrame.origin.y;
UIToolbar *t = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kToolbarFrame.origin.x, y,
                                                            kToolbarFrame.size.width, kToolbarFrame.size.height)] autorelease];
[t setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2, button1 , nil]];
t.clipsToBounds = NO;
t.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
t.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
t.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
                     | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
t.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
t.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
t.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
t.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [ColorUtil colorWithRed:129 withGreen:167 withBlue:186];
segmentedControl.frame = kSegmentedControlFrame; //CGRectMake(kSegmentedControlFrameX, kSegmentedControlY, kSegmentedControlWidth, kSegmentedControlHeight);
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.contentVerticalAlignment =  UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
segmentedControl.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
segmentedControl.clipsToBounds = NO;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
segmentedControl.center = CGPointMake(160, 22);
segmentedControl.momentary= NO;

[button1 release];
[button2 release];
[button3 release];

return t;
```

Thanks in advance,
Naira

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the toolbar is extending off the bottom of the screen, so that the segmented controller only appears closer to the bottom? There's no clear guard here against having a content view and toolbar size that together are taller than the visible screen area. Try positioning it with an `origin.y` value that is something along the lines of

```
CGFloat y = self.view.bounds.size.height - kToolbarFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: No, toolbar isn't extending off the bottom of the screen. Segmented control is shifted down 1px, its origin.y coordinate automatically set to 8, and I don't know how vertically center it.